# Preventing unauthenticated, direct access to OGC layers in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wms, authentication, proxy

Let's say that:

- I have centralized, single GeoServer for all application
- There's bunch of apps (that require login) that need WMS layers
- Web server of apps act as reverse proxy for GeoServer. Hence client that opens app-1, gets WMS layers by sending "http://app-1/geoserver/...".
- There's no direct access available from Client to Geoserver

[image]

Client can potentially get the WMS layer from Geoserver via the reverse proxy of these apps. Client can just request "http://app-1/geoserver/...". 
I need to make sure that:

- Client that is authenticated in app-1 gets the layer from "http://app-1/geoserver/..." (either via the web browser accessing app-1, or directly from browser url)
- Client that is NOT authenticated in app-1 gets ignored when requesting the layer from "http://app-1/geoserver/..."

How to do this?

Few notes: there's a load balancer in the cluster in the illustration.

Comment: Have you already read the documentation about security http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/index.html? Hopefully it could give you some ideas.